# how to create recap email template using c#?

Tags: c#, html

Hello every one i need to create recap email template using c#.i am create one small demo for that but this is not a propare o/p. can you please help me any one i want to my expected o/p.

this is my c# code :

```
 string MailBody1 = @"<div style='padding:10px;width: 100%;background-color:#f0f0f0;'>
                                                <div style='padding:25px;font-size: 20px;background-color:#403b3b;hight:20px;'></div>
                                                                                     <div style='text-align:left;'>Hey," + User.NAME + "</div>";
                        MailBody1 += @"This is for you.";

                        if (result.ListUsers[i].ListFeed != null)
                        {
                            var re1 = result.ListUsers[i].ListFeed.Distinct().ToList();
                            var Data1 = re1.GroupBy(t => t.FeedId).Select(g => g.First()).Take(5).ToList();
                            for (int j = 0; j < Data1.Count(); j++)
                            {
                                if (j % 2 == 0)
                                    MailBody1 += @"<div style='width:60%;'>";
                                else
                                    MailBody1 += @"<div style='width:40%;'>";

                                    MailBody1 += @"<img src='" + FeedMediaPath + Data1[j].Url.ToString();
                                    MailBody1 += @"' width='50%' hight='50%'>";

                                MailBody1 += @"<div style='width:50%;'><h5 style='text-align: justify;'>" + Data1[j].Description.ToString().Trim().TrimEnd('\r', '\n');
                                MailBody1 += @"</h5></div>";
                                MailBody1 += @"</div>";
                            }
                            MailBody1 += @"</div>";                                
                        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Excel To HTML using codebeautify.org</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div style='padding:10px;width: 100%;background-color:#f0f0f0;'>
    <div style='padding:25px;font-size: 20px;background-color:#403b3b;hight:20px;'></div>
    <div style='text-align:left;'>Hey,abc </div>this is for you
    <div style='width:60%;'>
     <img src='https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/QD8LXpFzcveyvSTClPgwt80WjuckwBOYZmN_0n9wuQ7fwbrsDolOLqKw6d-TrKlo4p8roqJRFBiiIv9aGEuMSQYDEpX3-bI0obhTxugtIfumw14XN_HnphepXiEwwOB6nSDZRu9IJF-QJaiwhHWk_ZEs-trMewpxoLiIC1Mv7B3bN3IE7FuJzYQ=s0-d-e1-ft#http://i.ytimg.com/vi/e2644ylntQQ/sddefault.jpg?w=640&h=360&feature=em-subs_digest&sigh=2OtiYi0Z-QhxEWZ6gj_6TWFOhoM' width='50%' hight='50%'>
      <div style='width:50%;'>
       <h5 style='text-align: justify;'>Test 1</h5>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div style='width:40%;'>
      <img src='https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/zaInbZ-UzqcTg5xtEn4_VxF3i9ncj8Tgp8rQsvo1GD7B59RMd5Rw2h3mD3osIDlhquxkbc7qhRDZrLIZAUgZdCHt9EguFsaeuaISqevRTHIWizJ9aPWWowAVC_l_9308OLChiiYJBlmPX-zZSef3D2Q5H22ajotF32ErbxfApKN2TLUYAE27a0g=s0-d-e1-ft#http://i.ytimg.com/vi/KiP9CYOL1QI/sddefault.jpg?w=640&h=360&feature=em-subs_digest&sigh=r5zSMmQQToPZF2zB-qD2Kr8BcIM' width='50%' hight='50%'>
       <div style='width:50%;'>
        <h5 style='text-align: justify;'>test 2</h5>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div style='width:60%;'>
       <img src='https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/avWBvpWny4vCI2Adub9AP6CTqjIc34m4KYbJr-KW-4HRkJ2-jiNPkkr2bkUtVC24tBVd5DJH2DdYtXRDI7kCFp26_ezvxvEwEw_LQWusri2vuaIv-x4s1NeflxkhfIakDPaS2D_vKtk-ACnW2m6DzD8BEgAQP1gepMtiZrf76ETIhgSlzEG4ChU=s0-d-e1-ft#http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Pz1KgzAoffc/sddefault.jpg?w=640&h=360&feature=em-subs_digest&sigh=nExBtDtnuvUc6I8_jxJn_31EIXQ' width='50%' hight='50%'>
        <div style='width:50%;'>
         <h5 style='text-align: justify;'>test 3.</h5>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div style='width:40%;'>
        <img src='https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/OUT6-vQzv1BCNkA5bKwhXOiGigztDtiwZZw0CFruqFZ7hXe0gNsNtZHBsb5h0iclReZ4qM-noAYN19U165hbPQKUSVVNms1aStJu-tTojniOwrCyvIPwqMCZOmCanzbLEMJE2Xf3y3aX8DynnPhmbxMviJuoMEGm23BANMiFBB4Rulx6vk0JXZA=s0-d-e1-ft#http://i.ytimg.com/vi/TeOecMBTnCI/sddefault.jpg?w=640&h=360&feature=em-subs_digest&sigh=5YLQxtwEYy697iqOBjTtn4BeQ0k' width='50%' hight='50%'>
         <div style='width:50%;'>
          <h5 style='text-align: justify;'>test 4</h5>
         </div>
        </div>
        <div style='width:60%;'>
         <img src='https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/-ev7NjEIxdkhOvzNISGpVkw149EuFOo9_PJx7hTAydN7I72BL5_D5bStTMzTNeypy7tlQ2LfVwIVa44RFZE-hPdHwCLix6y1I8ouC7W82Urqd3X9ZUnfXlpJ5J-J-IFu2cp43usB4dID5t4dlhkBCrpNJk4pRLnRisRCTfzyMrywn_K1ZKF9E2Y=s0-d-e1-ft#http://i.ytimg.com/vi/G1SdCNdPDL8/sddefault.jpg?w=640&h=360&feature=em-subs_digest&sigh=dNpeGzez7Ibl6LBrX9payANBkkE' width='50%' hight='50%'>
          <div style='width:50%;'>
           <h5 style='text-align: justify;'>test 5</h5>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </body>
      </html>
```

This is my expected o/p => 
[image]

i want to like this image in square but right now my image is come in one line so i don't want to this. any one how can do that then please let me know.

Comment: You need to use tables in your html email

Comment: @PaulKaram but how can i have no idea can you please tell me any give me some idea or answer

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this: http://blog.mailgun.com/transactional-html-email-templates/

Comment: @PaulKaram you mean i want to use whole in create as a table or just in loop create one table??

Comment: I mean that html emails sent should use tables to fix the layout, if you want to use 1 table or 100 tables it's up to you. The templates I showed you have some samples code if you want to follow, plus here's my question once about html emails: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40190055/html-on-outlook-for-android-not-showing-buttons-as-expected It's not the same concept, but it has a sample code as well.